# Refresh JScrollPane [Swing]

Tags: java, swing

I want to refresh JScrollPane and i used these methods `revalidate()` and `repaint()` method. However it doesn't work

Frame.java

```
    static ArrayList<String> studentList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    static JList<String> jlMemType;
    static JScrollPane scrollPane;
    .
    .
    public void panel() {
         pan= new JPanel();
         .
         .
         jlMemType = new JList(studentList.toArray());
         scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
         scrollPane.setViewportView(jlMemType);
         jlMemType.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
         jlMemType.addMouseListener(this);
         pan.add(scrollPane);
         .
         .
```

Socket.java

```
            Frame.studentList.add((String) rectinf.get("inff"));
            //System.out.println((String) rectinf.get("inff")); // it works data arrived
            Frame.scrollPane.revalidate();
            Frame.scrollPane.repaint();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static ArrayList<String> studentList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
static JList<String> jlMemType;
static JScrollPane scrollPane;
```

1. Don't use static variables. They are not required.
2. Don't keep an ArrayList. The data for the JList is contained in the ListModel. Any changes to the data must be done to the ListModel. The ListModel will then notify the JList to repaint itself. There is no need for revalidate() or repaint().

   jlMemType = new JList(studentList.toArray());

I don't believe you can use that code to add data to the JList. I think is will create a fixed size ListModel that can't be changed. Instead you need to create an instance of the DefaultListModel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` example code found by clicking on the `example index` link contains a working example that shows you how to do this.

```
Frame.studentList.add((String) rectinf.get("inff"));
```

Now, instead of updating the ArrayList you need to update the `DefaultListModel` directly. Again, the example from above shows you how to "add" and "remove" and item from the `DefaultListModel`.

Read the tutorial and start with the working code. The code will show you how to better structure your class so that you don't use static variables.

Comment: Thanks i changed arraylist to DefaultListModel and it works properly. (i used arraylist because i don't know how many data will arrive)

Comment: @Enes: as you have hopefully found out, the DefaultListModel also will accommodate an expanding (or contracting) collection of data.